# Https Node module not saving variable outside the function

Tags: node.js, https

So I've been trying to take some json info out of an API, but when I try to take the JSON object and assign it to an variable, it just doesn't work.

```
 var info = [];

https.get('https://br1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/sumname?api_key=',
(res) => {
  info.push(res.toString());
  
 res.on('data', (d) => {
  info.push(d.toString());
 });
 
 res.on('end', () =>{
   console.log(info);
 });
});

console.log(info);
<code>
```

Comment: listen for the data event on response object, push each chunk in the array, wait for the end event and build out of the array chunks a complete response with `info.concat().toString()` its asynchron, so you have to wait the response is completed. `https.get` returns a request stream, you have to call `.end()` on it to complete/end the request and start receiving the response.

Answer (score -1):

I actually had a similar issue recently when i started making GET API Calls. what i suspect the issue is --
https.get will return a promise. You need to resolve the promise before you can obtain the data within. Refer to the following post from 31piy

[Use result of HTTPS GET request [Node.js]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47986527/use-result-of-https-get-request-node-js/47986626)

This may prove helpful!

Comment: `https.get` does not return a promise. it returns a request object (stream)